# Joining multiple Spark Dataframes based on conditions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Based on the "SC" code I need to join SRCTable with either RefTable-1 or RefTable-2

Condition:
If SC is "D" , SRCTable join with RefTable-1 on KEY = KEY1, to get the value.
Else IF SC is "U" , SRCTable join with RefTable-2 on KEY = KEY2 & FK = KEY3 , to get the value.

This is the input spark dataframe.

```
SRCTable:
    -------------
    KEY |SC  |FK 
    -------------
    66  |D   | a
    67  |U   | b
    70  |D   | y
    71  |U   | q
    -------------
 RefTable-1:
    --------------
    KEY1 |Value  | 
    --------------
    66   |xyz1   | 
    67   |abc1   | 
    68   |fgr1   |
    69   |yte1   |
    70   |erx1   |
    71   |ter1   |
    --------------
 RefTable-2:
    --------------------
    KEY2 |KEY3  |Value  | 
    --------------------
    66   | a    |xyz2   | 
    67   | c    |abc2   | 
    67   | b    |fgr2   |
    69   | g    |yte2   |
    70   | y    |erx2   |
    71   | q    |ter2   |
    --------------------
```

Expected Output:

```
    --------------------
    KEY |SC  |FK |Value |
    -------------------- 
    66  |D   | a |xyz1  |
    67  |U   | b |fgr2  |
    70  |D   | y |erx1  |
    71  |U   | q |ter2  |
    ---------------------
```

Note: The Input tables will have millions of records, so need an optimized solution

Comment: it's hard to say without more details, how many million rows? are all the tables the same size? what have you tried?

In the end if you stick to dataframes, you'll have to do two joins, or a join and a union to standarise the two other dfs. maybe you can broadcast join if one of the tables is smaller than the other but it is hard to say with the info you've given

Comment: SRCTable will have around 1 million records , while RefTable-1,RefTable-2 will have around 1000 records each. please help with the solution

Comment: that is super small, if you want to stick to spark to do it then `srctable.join(broadcast(reftable1), join condition, 'left').join(broadcast(reftable2), join condition, 'left')`. You might want to filter down with a `where` clause if you are expecting some of the records not to match. 
Again it would be better for you to post your attempt and explain what the problem with it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code you can test using only join functions on `DataFrame`

```
val SRCTable = Seq((66, "D", "a"), (67, "U", "b"), (70, "D", "y"), (71, "U", "q")).toDF("KEY", "SC", "FK")
val RefTable1 = Seq((66, "xyz1"),(67, "abc1"),(68, "fgr1"),(69, "yte1"),(70, "erx1"),(71, "ter1")).toDF("KEY1", "Value")
val RefTable2 = Seq((66, "a", "xyz2"), (67, "c", "abc2"), (67, "b", "fgr2"), (69, "g", "yte2"), (70, "y", "erx2"), (71, "q", "ter2")).toDF("KEY2", "KEY3", "Value")

val join1 = SRCTable.where(SRCTable.col("SC").equalTo("D")).join(RefTable1, SRCTable.col("KEY") === RefTable1.col("KEY1")).select("KEY", "SC", "FK", "Value")
val join2 = SRCTable.where(SRCTable.col("SC").equalTo("U")).join(RefTable2, SRCTable.col("KEY") === RefTable2.col("KEY2") && SRCTable.col("FK") === RefTable2.col("KEY3") ).select("KEY", "SC", "FK", "Value")

join1.unionAll(join2).show
```

If you have any performances issues, I advice you to look at how to well partition your data and also look at the Broadcast object if one of your DataFrame is small